# How to fix wobbly table/improve stability?

Tags: table, desk

i want to fix my table so it doesn't wobbly sideway. it's a little annoying because when i move sligthly my monitor goes shaky because of the wobbly. i try to use using this "white thing" and it help to stabilize but, still need improvement.
thank you and if you have solution please give the picture to for example.

english is not my native languange sorry if there are mispelled word.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want your table to be more rigid.  Triangles make things rigid.  The white things you added are shelf brackets and they're basically small triangles.  Larger more triangular triangles will have a better effect.  There may also be existing fasteners on the table you can tighten

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. These brackets are the right idea, just use bigger ones. Also, you've got a pretty good chance of finding them in black so they're not so visibly obvious. If you can't find black, pick up a can of spray paint in black or dark brown and paint them before installing them.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle is one of the most stable structures around. You could make the third side of a triangle, by using a diagonally placed piece of wood going from the top inside corner (where the "white thing" is) down to the top of the opposite foot. Even better, repeat this on the other side.

It may mean you lose some knee room under the table, but by screwing the struts as far back as you can, there should still be enough clearance. The struts could be as little as 2"x1", shaped to fit at each end. Or metal , which may or may not be easier to fix in place.